# Gatling Script is throwing a warning: "imported `Login' is permanently hidden by definition of object Login in package actions"

Tags: scala, exception, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have encountered an issue while running my Gatling Script in IntelliJ.
I have multiple scripts to be executed, that involve a login to be executed once, and then the rest of the scripts/flows.
Everything was running fine for the first 4-5 scripts, until I encountered this warning -> " imported `Login' is permanently hidden by definition of object Login in package actions" in the newly created script. Ever since, every script, that includes even the previously running scripts, has started throwing this warning. As a result, even if I ignore and go ahead with executing the script, it stops moving ahead and remains stuck, later throwing this blockage in the console as well ->  imported`Login' is permanently hidden by definition of object Login in package actions.

I have followed exactly the same scripting practice that I have been doing for the earlier scripts with no deviation from the usual.

Flow:

1. Execute Login
2. Capture the session id generated during login action.
3. Create a new script and import the Login action in that script, thereby using the captured session id value.
4. The problem arises when I import the Login action packages in my new script, as I start seeing the exception in my newly created script only.

Please help.

Thanks!

---

```
//Login Action that is being imported to another action below:


    package jda.Scheduler.actions

    import io.gatling.core.Predef._
    import io.gatling.http.Predef._
    import scala.concurrent.duration._



    object Login {

      def loginAction(): ChainBuilder = {

        group("Login") {

          exec(http("Main_Request")
            .post("/******/****/login?loginName=c***&password=****")
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
            .header("User-Agent", "okhttp/2.7.5")
            .body(StringBody(""""""))
            .check(status.in(200))

            .check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "REFSSessionID(.+?);").find.saveAs("SessionID")))
        }
      }
    }


//Different Action where Login is being imported and issues faced:

package jda.Scheduler.actions

import jda.Scheduler.actions.Login ---> Warning appears (imported 'Login' is permanently hidden by definition of object Login in package actions)


import jda.Scheduler.actions.CreateUserAction ---> Warning appears (imported 'CreateUserAction' is permanently hidden by definition of object CreateUserAction in package actions)

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object UpdateEmployeeAction {


  def updateEmployeeAction(): ChainBuilder = {

  group ("updateEmployee"){
    exec(http("Main_Request")
        .get("/******/****/****/api/***-***/employees/${userID}")

    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

    .header("REFSSessionID", "${SessionID}")  ---> This part is being captured and saved //in Login action

    .body(StringBody("""{

  "id": ${userID}, --> This part (${userID}) is being captured and saved in another action, just //like Login Action. Even this is creating same issues.

    "badgeNumber": ${userloginname},
    "birthDate": "1900-07-31T00:00:00",
    "hireDate": "2019-08-12T00:00:00",
    "seniorityDate": "2019-08-12T00:00:00",
    "minorStatus": "Minor",
    "isManagement": false,
    "managerPassword": null,
    "managerInSchedule": false,
    "generateException": true,
    "generateAlerts": true,
    "canWorkUnassignedJobs": true,
    "schedulingTypeCode": "Manual",
    "ignoreBiometricValidation": false,
    "punchValidationCode": "NoScheduleValidation"
}"""))

    .check(status.in(200))

        )}}
  }
```

Comment: You're going to have to post your code.

Comment: @JamesWarr I've posted the code in the answer section as it was too long for the comment section. Thanks!